# Quadratic reciprocity and Pfister forms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $p,q$ be different primes unequal to $2$. Let $(a/b)$ denote the Legendre Symbol. The following holds:

$q\text{ is a square }\bmod p \Longleftrightarrow (q/p) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow X^2+qY^2 = 0$ has a solution over $\mathbb{Q}^*_p$.

So $X^2 = q + mp$

If i set $Y = 1$

i get
$$X^2 = qY^2 + mp.$$

So

$$X^2 - qY^2 = 0 \bmod p$$

holds.

But the sign of $qY^2$ doenst match with my beginning statement. That would mean that

$$(q/p) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow X^2 - qY^2 = 0\text{ has a solution over }\mathbb{Q}^*_p$$

holds.

I am confused. Is my primal statement false?

Comment: How do you show $(q|p) = 1 \Rightarrow x^2 + qy^2 = 0$ has a solution in ${\mathbf Q}_p^\times$?

Comment: I have no idea.I am sure i red it in some script. I am basically asking if this statement is wrong. Inst it?

Comment: Please try looking at an actual *example*. Take $p=3$. The first prime $q$ such that $(q|p) = 1$ is $7$. Does $X^2 + 7Y^2 = 0$ have a solution in $\mathbf Q_3^\times$?

Comment: Well $\sqrt{7}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}_3$ but since 3 = 4k + 3 it follows that $\sqrt{-1}$ isnt contained. So the equation shouldnt have a solution. I think i cited the "lemma" wrong. Its pretty clear now.

Comment: Whether or not $-1$ is a square in the 3-adics is related to its value mod 3, not mod 4, so saying $3 = 4k + 3$ is not relevant. Anyway, forget $7$ and $-1$; just look directly at $-7$, which is $2 \bmod 3$.

Comment: Looking at the equation mod 3 has the solution (1,1).

Comment: ??? You are saying $X^2 + 7Y^2 = 0$ has $(1,1)$ as a solution mod 3, but there are *no* solutions mod 3.

Comment: I said: $X^2 - 7Y^2 = X^2 + 2Y^2 = 0 $ mod $3$ has solution (1,1). So in the statement in my first post the sign of q has to be switched. Thats what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is (a very weak version of) Hensel's lemma : if $q$ is not divisible by $p$, $X^2 - q$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ if and only if it has a solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$ (this is because $X^2 - q$ is separable in $\mathbb{F}_p$).

So indeed $(q/p)=1$ iff $q$ in a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (which is equivalent to your equation $X^2 - qY^2 = 0$, though using two variables is overkill).